# In NodeJs 8.* how do I apply Async / Await on http.get?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

The following code gets the result asyncronously from the specified url, and I would like to return `parsed` variable out of getData method, after I receive the data, making use of async/await in nodejs version 8.* (without callback function).

```
function getData(v, r) {
    var path = 'http://some.url.com';
    var parsed = "";
    http.get({
        path: path
    }, function(res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            parsed = JSON.parse(body);
            // now I would like to return parsed from this function without making use of callback functions, and make use of async/await;
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
    return parsed;
};
```

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: First you create an asynchronous operation that returns a promise.  Then, you can use async/await with that function that returns a promise.  So, read up about promises first.

Answer (score 0):

First off let me say I recommend using the npm package `request` to deal with http gets, that said.

**1.) Use a Promise** (await does this in the background)

```
function getData(v, r) {
  var path = 'http://some.url.com';
  var parsed = '';
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get({
      path: path
    }, function(res) {
      var body = '';
      res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', function() {
        parsed = JSON.parse(body);
        resolve(parsed);
      });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      reject(e.message);
    });
  });
};
```

Then usage would be

```
getData(v, r)
  .then(success => console.log(success))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

**2.) or callbacks** You could pass in a callback as a parameter to `getData` (i.e. `getData(v, r, callback)`) then within the body of your function call it via `callback(parsed)` or `callback(error_msg)`.

Then usage would be:

```
getData(v, r, result=>console.log(result))
```

or easier to read maybe:

```
function callback(res) { 
  console.log(res) 
}
getData(v, r, callback)
```

Comment: You should test your first example, because it won't work.

Comment: your right, so sorry, im actually unsure how to use await in this case :/

Comment: You'd use `await` with your third example, because `await` works with promises: `await getData(v, r)`